# Generate HTML using Javascript and then interpret it with Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm generating an HTML table which renders like this:

```
<table id="#webappname">
    <tr ng-repeat="data in d">
        <td>1 {{data}}</td>
        <td>2 hey !</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

To generate this i'm using `angular.element("#webapp").append("<table [...]</table>");`

I would want the angular js template in the table to be interpreted by Angular (a little bit like `jQuery.live()`). What should I use ?

Comment: Can I ask why you create the table through vanilla Javascript or jQuery? Could you use an `ng-include` with template snippets instead? It's just that, I believe, that hand-writing basic HTML like this isn't best practice.

Comment: @gonzofish I create a javascript library which allows you to add a table to your html binded to some data. This library uses angular to reload the data automatically. But I'm not so familiar to angular.js so I didn't know of a way to do this.

Comment: do you have plunkr or fiddle that has a preview of what you're trying to accomplish? I believe you're trying to allow users to dynamically create tables? Knowing your end state could help me get you more familiar with AngularJS best practices so you can make what you're trying to do easier on yourself!

Comment: @gonzofish Thanks but it is okay, $compile did the trick ! :)
Though, the users are not able to create dynamically tables. I have widgets on my page and I want the agreed developers to use my library to create their widgets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You should compile it and link it to a scope:

```
var table = angular.element("<table [...]</table>");
$compile(table)($scope);
angular.element("#webapp").append(table);
```